# Replace blank values in one row with text

Tags: r

I need to replace blank values in the second row of my data set with text ("dummy" in this example), without overwriting blank values in the remainder of the dataset.

For example, if you start with a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(x1=c("X","Y",""),x2=c("Z","",""),x3=c("A","B","C"),x4=c("E","",""))
```

I would like a line of code to convert it to:

```
df <- data.frame(x1=c("X","Y",""),x2=c("Z","dummy",""),x3=c("A","B","C"),x4=c("E","dummy",""))
```

I have tried:

```
df[df == ""] <- "dummy"
```

however this replaces *all* blank values, instead of only those in the second row.
I have also tried combining this with df[2,] in various ways with no success.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: For second row only: df[2,][df[2,]==""] <- 'dummy'

Comment: Are your columns `factors`?

Comment: Thank you very much -  df[2,][df[2,]==""] <- 'dummy' is exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps its easier to make things not factors in the first place:

```
df <- data.frame(x1=c("X","Y",""),x2=c("Z","",""), 
                 x3=c("A","B","C"),x4=c("E","",""), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df[df == ""] <- "YO"
#df
#  x1 x2 x3 x4
#1  X  Z  A  E
#2  Y YO  B YO
#3 YO YO  C YO
```

If you want everything to be a factor once your done you could try:

```
df <- data.frame(x1=c("X","Y",""), x2=c("Z","",""), 
                 x3=c("A","B","C"), x4=c("E","",""))

new <- as.data.frame( sapply(df, function(x){ w <- as.character(x)
                                              w[w == ""] <- "DUMMY"
                                              return(w) } ))

str(new)
#'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ x1: Factor w/ 3 levels "DUMMY","X","Y": 2 3 1
# $ x2: Factor w/ 2 levels "DUMMY","Z": 2 1 1
# $ x3: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
# $ x4: Factor w/ 2 levels "DUMMY","E": 2 1 1
```

EDIT as per your comment:

```
# you still need to set things to characters first
df <- data.frame(x1=c("X","Y",""),x2=c("Z","",""), 
                 x3=c("A","B","C"),x4=c("E","",""), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# then
df[2,][df[2,] == ""] <- "DUMMY"

df
#  x1    x2 x3    x4
#1  X     Z  A     E
#2  Y DUMMY  B DUMMY
#3           C
```

Comment: +1 I was thinking the same way, but what if OP wants to keep the factors?

Comment: Thanks. I am happy to have them as characters (stringsAsFactors=F). Unfortunately, the solution I am after will only replace blanks in the 2nd row - the solution above replaces blanks with "YO" in the third row as well.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Question is answered in the comments on my original question.

Comment: @user3070455 yes although the comment didn't solve the factor problem